# no "UITableViewCell Subclass" option in XCode under AddNewfile?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, xcode4

In some web articles in the past I see an option in Xcode to add a new file using a "UITableViewCell subclass" template.   For example [here](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/).

I can't see this in Xcode myself (I have the latest version, v4 of xcode).

Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Choose `Objective-C class`
2. Press *Next*
3. Select `UITableViewCell` from the dropdown menu

[image: Point 1]

[image: Point 3]

*It is a bit weird but it is.*

Comment: Back in Xcode 3 I seem to remember it also generating an xib. In XC4 I can see a way to create a view, but they always look like a full window, and I just want to customise the look of  my tablecell. Is there another step after the ones above that I need to complete before I can visually drag a label onto a view?

Answer (score 1):

You want to add an Objective C class (Under Cocoa Touch), then you'll be presented with a "Subclass of..." dialog. Select UITableViewCell.